# Upload to specific Fan Page Album without user perms

Tags: facebook, photo, facebook-page

I'm trying to replicate the same functionality as someone else has already achieved on this page here:
http://www.facebook.com/PowerPhotoUploader?sk=app_152884604799537
am not bothered about the forced like fangate part, can do that no probs.
I need to achieve this without requesting any user perms the same way they have

I've got close, but not quite right yet.
Have created a test album on this page: http://www.facebook.com/pages/Demo-Album-Upload/227979503931257?sk=app_153866511376478

The code I have is uploading my specified image, however it is ignoring the album id I input and instead, uploading to an album on my own profile.

Code so far is:

```
<?php
$app_id = "XXXXXXXXXXX";
$app_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
require 'facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array( 'appId' => $app_id, 'secret' => $app_secret, 'cookie' => true, 'fileUpload' => true,));
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
//print_r ($signed_request);
$page_id         = $signed_request["page"]["id"];
//Upload To Page Album 
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$album_id ='59125';  
$file_path  ='image2.gif';
$args = array('message' => 'Photo Caption');
$args['image'] = '@' . realpath($file_path);
$data = $facebook->api('/'.$album_id.'/photos', 'post', $args);
print_r($data);
?>
```

Have already read through a lot of forum material, have set the filuploadsupport, set file upload to true, but most of the info I can find so far reuires perms & access token, however sample above has managed to achieve with neither - any thoughts?

Regards Tony

Answer (score 0):

Tony the trick here is that you only need one access token, not a new one for each user. The idea is that the user is not posting to the page, you are posting to the page, so you do not need an access token from the user. However since this is a secure call to Facebook you still need to provide an access token that has the ability to publish to the page.

The simplest route to get an access token that you can use would be to manually give the application the manage_pages and offline_access permissions for your account. Then just grab the access token for for your account and use it for all calls.

Comment: Hi there jtymann, many thanks for that, after lots of trial and error finally figured it out, as an admin set index to request to manage pages and offline, then got access token as user, then got page access token for that particular page and hard-coded it into tab page - many thanks, now working. Using this method will I ever need to get page access token again, ie will it ever expire or will offline access guarantee it stays infinite?

Comment: Tony, glad to hear you got it working. As per access tokens expiring, currently access tokens that have been given offline access will only expire if you remove the app or change your password.

Comment: Hi there jtymann, I have the photo upload now working correctly and going to the correct album, now facing a new problem and unsure what to do about it. Once the upload is complete the graph seems to just print a JSON response of the photo id directly to the browser automatically and can find no way to control its output.
page/App I've been working on is here: http://www.facebook.com/pages/Demo-Frank-by-OCBC/227979503931257?sk=app_153866511376478 Any ideas most appreciated on how to control the returned response